# Display calendar with checkboxes in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, calendar

I'm displaying calendar with checkboxes to manage holidays. I managed to get dates for each month with the checkboxes. However i want to display the dates with days accordingly just like a calendar. Likewise January started with Monday, so my listing should begin with Monday and Feb starts with Thursday and so on...

Below is my code.

**Holiday.cs**

```
public class Holiday
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string selectedmonth { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> months  { get; set; }
        public string selectedyear { get; set; }
        public SelectList year { get; set; }
        public List<DateTime> dateList { get; set; }
        public List<Models.Days> dayList { get; set; }
    }
```

**Days.cs**

```
public class Days
    {
        public string dayid { get; set; }
        public string dayname { get; set; }
        public bool ischecked { get; set; }
    }
```

**HolidayController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            Models.Holiday holiday = new Models.Holiday();
            Context.Holiday contHoliday = new Context.Holiday();

            holiday.months = contHoliday.Months;
            holiday.year = new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(2008, DateTime.Now.Year - 2007).Reverse());
            holiday.dateList = GetDates(2018, 1);

            DateTime startday = holiday.dateList[0];
            string startday1 = startday.DayOfWeek.ToString();

            holiday.dayList = new List<Models.Days>();

            for(int i=0;i<holiday.dateList.Count;i++)
            {
                holiday.dayList.Add(new Models.Days { dayid = holiday.dateList[i].ToShortDateString().ToString(), dayname = holiday.dateList[i].Day.ToString(), ischecked = false });
            }

            List<DateTime> hollst = contHoliday.getDates(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString(),DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());

            if (hollst.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var date in hollst)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < holiday.dayList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (date.ToShortDateString() == holiday.dayList[i].dayid)
                        {
                            holiday.dayList[i].ischecked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(holiday);
        }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.dayList.Count; i++)
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.dayList[i].dayname)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.dayList[i].ischecked)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.dayList[i].dayid)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.dayList[i].dayname)
                </td>

            }
        </tr>




 </table>
```

[image]

Comment: You should start with a view model containing a collection of a `Week` model representing each week in the month, and the `Week` model contains a property for each day of the week so that you can use nested `foreach` loops in the view to represent your calendar.

Comment: Isn't there any way taking weekend days, and simply applying some conditions to manage calendar?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean (surely you want to display a table representing a month which means you need to create rows representing weeks in the month, and columns representing days in the week)

Comment: Yes, you understand it right. Adding an image to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Which means you need to start with the view models I noted above so that your view code becomes (say) `@foreach(var week in Model.Weeks) { <tr>@foreach(var day in week.Days) { <td>.....` to generate the table

Comment: I'm collecting all months dates in a Days class and Holiday class contains that property in which I'm containing all the days of the month. Let me add that to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162719/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user100020).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `modulus` operator to conditionally generate a new table row every 7th element, but to make this easier, the collection of `Days` will need to include values for all the dates represented by the table (i.e. including any days in the the months before and after the current month - which you can then conditionally hide or display in a faded style).

I would suggest that you modify you model to be

```
public class DayVM
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Day { get { return Date.Day; } }
    public bool IsCurrent { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Then your code in the controller method to populate the collection would be

```
// The following 2 values might come from parameters in your GET method
int month = 2;
int year = 2018;

DateTime firstOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
int index = (int)firstOfMonth.DayOfWeek;
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
int totalDays = 35; // 5 rows by 7 days
if (daysInMonth + index > 35) // 6 rows by 7 days
{
    totalDays = 42;
}

IEnumerable<DateTime> existingHolidays = .... // your code to get any existing dates that should be marked as selected
List<DayVM> dates = new List<DayVM>();
DateTime startDate = firstOfMonth.AddDays(-index); // date of first column in first row
for (int i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
{
    DateTime date = startDate.AddDays(i);
    DayVM day = new DayVM { Date = date };
    if (date.Month == month)
    {
        day.IsCurrent = true;
        if (existingHolidays.Contains(date))
        {
            day.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
    dates.Add(day);
}
model.dayList = dates;
```

Then in the view

```
<tr>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.dayList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0 && i % 7 == 0)
        {
            @:</tr><tr> // close and start new row
        }
        <td>
            @if(Model.dayList[i].IsCurrent)
            {
                <span>@Model.dayList[i].Day</span>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.dayList[i].IsSelected)
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.dayList[i].Date)  
        </td>
    }
</tr>
```

Refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tVa6ey) for an example (note the fiddle includes some alternative features you may wish to consider, such as hiding the checkbox and using color coding to display the selected dates - clicking on a cell toggles the checkbox state, and using different styles for non-selectable dates - e.g. weekends)

Comment: The styling and the concept of hiding checkbox and using color coding to display the selected dates is a good way to present the calendar. This is a very good example and fulfills need of exact requirement. Thank you @Stephen Muecke :)

Comment: You may also want to consider color coding any existing public holidays, and marking them as non-selectable